# CSS3 animations - delay, stop and play

Tags: html, css, web

I am not very good at CSS3 animations so I need some help to improve the output.

I am trying to achieve the Windows8  tile effect and I am nearly done.

I am trying to achieve this
[image]

and here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/InsaneCoder/jaLgd/)

The CSS which flips is the following.

The suffix '1' is for block1 ,'2' for block2 and so on 'til 5 for five blocks.

```
/*block one*/

    .flip-container1, .front1, .back1 {
      position:relative;
      width: 432px;
      height: 140px;
    }

    .flipper1 {
      -webkit-transition: 0.6s;
      -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;

      -moz-transition: 0.6s;
      -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;

      transition: 0.6s;
      transform-style: preserve-3d;

      position: relative;
    }

    .front1, .back1 {
      -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
      -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
      backface-visibility: hidden;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      background: #2FB1BE;
    }



    .vertical1.flip-container1 {
      position: relative;
    }

      .vertical1 .back1 {
        -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);
        -moz-transform: rotateX(180deg);
        transform: rotateX(180deg);
      }

      .vertical1.flip-container1 .flipper1 {
        -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 70px;
        -moz-transform-origin: 100% 70px;
        transform-origin: 100% 70px;
      }
@keyframes myFirst{
        from{
        webkit-transform: rotateX(-180deg);
        -moz-transform: rotateX(-180deg);
        transform: rotateX(-180deg);
      }
      to{
        webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);
        -moz-transform: rotateX(180deg);
        transform: rotateX(180deg);
      }
  }
  @-webkit-keyframes myFirst{
    from{
        webkit-transform: rotateX(-180deg);
        -moz-transform: rotateX(-180deg);
        transform: rotateX(-180deg);
      }
      to{
        webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);
        -moz-transform: rotateX(180deg);
        transform: rotateX(180deg);
      }
  }
  .vertical1.flip-container1 .flipper1{
    animation:myFirst 3s;
    -webkit-animation:myFirst 3s;
    animation-direction:normal;
    -webkit-animation-direction:normal;
    animation-iteration-count:infinite;
  }
```

Now I want to solve the following two problems:

1-  I want that only one tile flips at a time.
     Currently, I have applied different animation times which looks fine but multiple tiles are flipping at a time.

2- I want the animation of a particular tile to stop when the backside is shown and then move to another tile and when again its turn comes then front side is shown again. Currently, it shows front side and then immediately shows back side and then pauses for a while.

Answer (score 0):

For your first problem, you'll want to use the `:hover` pseudo tag, and if needed also use tile-specific ids.

I don't quite understand what you mean by "then move to another tile and when again its turn comes then front side is shown again". But, you have `animation-iteration-count:` set to `infinite` so of course the animation will continue on infinitely.

It seems you don't quite understand CSS animations/transitions fully yet. Perhaps you should practice with just making a box grow on mouse hover, then work your way up to making just 1 box flip. [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/) has a great reference to [CSS Animations](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_animations.asp).

Comment: :Let me explain it clearly.Suppose I have 2 tiles and each tile has two sides side1 and side2.Currently,both tiles show side1 (front side).Now ,by **then move to another tile and when again its turn comes then front side is shown again** I mean that first tile shows side2 then second tile shows side2,then first tile shows side1 ,then second shows side1,then first shows side2 ,then second side2 and so on.